# Unable to delete a file in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vmware, windows-xp, delete

I have a undeleted file in windows xp.This is a file leftover after deleting google chrome and is present in `C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\old_Cache_000`.

File name is 4 and 3 square boxes after that and also the file changes to weird names after trying to delete in windows.File size is 0 bytes.  
I have tried every software available by using google and different solutions but nothing worked.  
So,I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in VMware Player and used shared folders to access the windows folders in Ubuntu.

Now the location of file is `mnt/hgfs/Documents and Settings/Admin/Local Settings/Application Data/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/old_Cache_000`.

I am unable to delete the old_Cache_000 directory because it shows the directory is not empty but by using ls -la,nothing shows in the directory except . and .. files.How to delete that file or its parent directory?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with follow.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs
```

please use "`ntfsck`" command and fix issues of ntfs filesystem.
and after you reboot or remount the filesystem, please use follow command.

```
$ sudo rm -rf "mnt/hgfs/Documents and Settings/Admin/Local Settings/Application Data/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/old_Cache_000"
```

Comment: ntfs-3g is already the newest version.ntfsprogs has no installation.Nothing happens after using ntfsck command.I have rebooted and tried to delete but same result:cannot remove:directory not empty.

Comment: did you use "ntfsck /dev/sda1"? or just "ntfs"?

Comment: I have used ntfsck /dev/sda1,it gives Boot sector: Bad jump.Boot sector: Bad NTFS magic.Boot sector: Bytes per sector is 0.Volume size is set to zero.First attribute must be after the header (0).  Then the cursor keeps on blinking

Comment: "mount" command's result?

Comment: please check mount status that read only and mounted filesystem

Comment: The output of mount is large,this is the line with /dev/sda1:/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)

Comment: oh, can you chat with me?

Comment: I don't have enough rep points for chat

Answer (score 0):

and welcome!

Have you tried this command:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /hgfs/Documents and Settings/Admin/Local Settings/Application Data/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default
```

Comment: Yes,I have tried that command already and rm -rf * also,it shows cannot remove:directory not empty.